# Añadir un circulo en Google Maps Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Quiero dibujar un círculo en la vista del mapa. Quiero que el usuario ingrese el radio y para ese radio, tengo que mostrar el círculo en el mapa. Después de eso, tengo que mostrar marcadores en algunas ubicaciones de ese círculo.

Comment: Bienvenido al sito .Jose.. !!! te doy la bienvenida y te invito a que realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Además revisa [ask] que te da información para realizar una buena pregunta y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas!. Es importante modifiques el formato de tu pregunta agregando lo que has tratado o investigado, saludos.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

agregar un circulo es sensillo
Una ves que tengas el mapa listo, debes hacer lo siguiente

```
GoogleMap map;
 // ... get a map.
 // Add a circle in Sydney
 Circle circle = map.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
     .center(new LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689))
     .radius(10000)
     .strokeColor(Color.RED)
     .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```

Informacion sacada de [android developers](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle)

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero el círculo no se muestra en el mapa :/ hay otra forma de agregar el círculo?

Comment: Hola!, no sabria si hay otra forma, esto esta sacaado de la documentacion oficial, por favor revisa si en tu codigo no hay algun error